# How to get the correct a:nth-child into an <input> with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, css-selectors, livesearch

I'm trying to code a pretty simple live search of some food from a database. So far so good, i'm trying since 2 days to get the right content to my input value. To imagine what I mean, here is a picture:

### [Description, how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/varbM.png)

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $("#search").keyup(function()
 {
  $("#here").show();
  var x = $(this).val();
  $.ajax(
  {
   type:'GET',
   url:'search.php',
   data:'q='+x,
   success:function(data)
   {
    $("#here").html(data);
   }
  }); 
 });
 
 $( "#here" ).click(function() {
  var index = $("#here a").index();
  
  var content = $("#here a:nth-child(" + index + ")").text();
  $('#search').val(content);
  $( "#here" ).css( "display", "none" );
    });
  
    $( "#here" ).css( "display", "none" );
});
```

```css
#here{
 width:400px;
 height: 300px;
 border: 1px solid grey;
 display: none;
}

#here a{
 display: block;
 width: 98%;
 padding: 1%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> Live Search!!!</h1>
<input type="search" name="search" id="search">
<div id="here"><div>
```

And here is my php code:

```html
<?php

if(!empty($_GET['q']))
{
 $index = 1;
 include 'connect.php';
 $q=$_GET['q'];
 $query="select * from Nahrungsmittel WHERE Name like '%$q%'";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

 while($output=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  echo '<a>',$output['Name'].'</a>';
  $index++;
 }
}
?>
```

I tried to get the nth-child number with the jquery index() function. But it does not really work.

Someone who knows why? Would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
var index = $("#here a").index();
```

to this:

```
var index = $(this).index();
```

basically you're grabbing the index's of every "a" in #here, rather than the one you actually clicked on

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I tried that. Before, the index var was always 0, so there wasn't any text in the <input> field. After i changed it to your suggestion, the index var is always 5 and so he puts everytime the nth-child(5) in the <input> value. I really don't get why....